# How to remove an item from an object

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var map = {};
map["S"] = "s";
map["C"] = "c";
map["D"] = "d";
```

How can I fully remove item map["S"]? I don't want to end up with a null object so using delete map["S"] wouldn't work.

Comment: Why do you think `delete map["S"]` will leave a null behind? Shouldn't it just behave like JS? Did you try it?

Comment: I just realized I had a typo and was getting [Object object] when printing the result. After I fixed that I saw that the item was successfully removed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> How can I fully remove item map["S"]? I don't want to end up with a null object so using delete map["S"]

`delete` does *clear it completely*:

```
interface IMap {
[name: string]: string;
}

var map: IMap = {};
map["S"] = "s";
map["C"] = "c";
map["D"] = "d";

delete map["S"];
console.log(map);
console.log(map["S"],map["non-existent"]); // undefined,undefined
console.log(Object.keys(map)); // ["C","D"]
```

Comment: This appears to leave an empty entry in the map?

Comment: **No**, delete map entry will not leave an empty entry

Comment: It actually does leave an empty entry

Comment: But it actually doesn't

Comment: but it actually does